# Help needed for cis orcad + pspice

Tags: gain, pspice, phase

I have been trying to simulate a circuit on pspice. Simulation worked really well and pspice has given me the expected diagrams of gain and phase. I am having difficulty thought on how to use the measurement toolbar to find both gain margin and phase margin. Does anyone know how to fill the variables (1,2) of getting the needed values. My output is v(vout1). Thank you in advance!!!

[image]

Comment: What does [the manual](https://www.montana.edu/aolson/ee503/pspcref.pdf) say?

Answer (score 1):

GainMargin(1,2):

- Argument 1 is phase of the trace. In your case it is `(v(vout1))`
- Argument 2 is gain of the trace in dB. In your case it is `dB(v(vout1))`

PhaseMargin(1,2):

- Argument 1 is gain of the trace in dB. In your case it is `dB(v(vout1))`
- Argument 2 is phase of the trace. In your case it is `(v(vout1))`